# Multiple Quit messages in my *Messages* buffer

Tags: debugging

When I hold `C-p` or `C-n` to navigate any page, the movement is jerky and I get multiple `Quit` messages in my `*Messages*` buffer.

I checked the `C-h l` to see the commands ran, it only has the `C-n [next-line]` I expect.

This does not happen in Org mode, but it happens in many of the programming modes. 
For example, in YAML mode, it happens.

Here is my list of all active modes where this is happening.

`Enabled minor modes: Ansible Ansible-Doc Async-Bytecomp-Package
Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Clean-Aindent
Column-Number Delete-Selection Diff-Auto-Refine Discover Display-Time
Electric-Indent Emojify File-Name-Shadow Flycheck Flycheck-Pos-Tip
Flyspell Font-Lock Gdb-Many-Windows Global-Auto-Complete
Global-Auto-Revert Global-Discover Global-Eldoc Global-Emojify
Global-Flycheck Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit Global-Hl-Line
Global-Magit-File Global-Pointback Global-Semantic-Idle-Scheduler
Global-Semanticdb Global-Smart-Shift Global-Smart-Tab Global-Undo-Tree
Golden-Ratio Goto-Address Helm Helm-Autoresize Highlight-Indentation
Keyfreq Keyfreq-Autosave Line-Number Magit-Auto-Revert Magit-File
Mouse-Wheel Nyan Override-Global Persistent-Scratch-Autosave Pointback
Projectile Pyvenv Recentf Semantic Shell-Dirtrack Simpleclip
Size-Indication Smart-Shift Smart-Tab Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree
Volatile-Highlights Which-Key Winner Yas Yas-Global`

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Using `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` gave me this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
redisplay_internal\ \(C\ function\)()
```

I have shared my full `init.el` here - https://gist.github.com/darshanime/c65b4bb318db722a66b42753f1bc4041

Comment: Try typing:  `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` and then go about your business.  Emacs should generate a backtrace automatically the next time a quit signal occurs.  Then, please edit your question with the output of the backtrace.

Comment: Start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and see if you can reproduce the problem. If you can then simplify your report here, providing a step-by-step recipe (from `emacs -Q`), saying what you see at each step and what you expected to see. If you cannot, then bisect your init file to find the culprit. No need to show us a long list of modes where this happens - just show a recipe for one such mode (e.g. YAML). What's important is to simplify/narrow the test space and provide a recipe.

Comment: You can also show the message that is printed. And you can check what command `C-n` is bound to when this happens. You can also use `M-x debug-on-entry COMMAND`, where `COMMAND` is the command bound to `C-n` (assuming that the message came from using `C-n`) - then step through the debugger, to see just what happens. But even if you decide to do this, start by simplifying the test space - start Emacs with `emacs -Q` etc.

Comment: It doesn't happen with `emacs -Q`. I have added the `toggle-debug-on-quit` output as well.